# How can I have a template folder outside my Django project

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm working on an Open Source Django app and created some design for it. Now a customer wants to use it's own, copyrighted, design. After reading the Django docs I created a separate, private, GIT repository that I want to use for the new design. I got it almost working by adding 2 items to the settings; an extra entry to look for templates in a folder "funder_custom_templates" and an extra entry to look for static files in the same location. This is how I configured TEMPLATES and STATICFILES_DIR:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '..', '..', 'funder_custom_templates'),
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'fundraiser.context_processors.cart',
            ],
        },
    },
]
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '..', '..', 'funder_custom_templates','static'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

This works for overriding the base design located in the PROJECT_DIR/templates/base.html, when I create funder_customer_templates/base.html and for all the static files as expected. But I also want to override app specific template files like blog/templates/blog/blog_index_page.html

I tried to put these files in the root of funder_custom_templates and I tried to mimic the app folders structure in funder_custom_templates but that doesn't load the app specific templates. Is there a way to solve this?

Example project files, with the folder structure, located at: https://github.com/acidjunk/funder/tree/develop/

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't put `blog_index_page.html` in the root of `funder_custom_templates`, but in a `blog` subdirectory of it, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Please show the layout of the templates in `funder_custom_templates`.

Comment: I tested, the layout stuff, it by using the base.html from the main design with some added text so I could see that the correct "custom" template was loaded.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides: I tried both approaches, without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `app_directories.Loader` class to load templates (specified by setting `'APP_DIRS': True,`), then for app specfic templates Django will iterate over your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting looking for a specific template file. The important thing here is that it does so in order.

So if you want to override `blog/templates/blog/blog_index_page.html` then you will need to have a `custom_blog/templates/blog/blog_index_page.html` inside an application that comes before `blog`.

I recommend wrapping up all custom static resources in their own django application and python package. This way you can simply install the package from its private repo and add it to the list of installed apps to override any static content and templates.

See Django's docs for more details on template loading: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader

Comment: So, basically, your are suggesting an extra app called "aaa" that will be used to override all the templates and static assets from the other apps. I will try that, I was hoping that Django had a way to let it load the templates and assets from outside the project dir. (e.g. honor the APP_DIRS: True for non app folders that contain templates.